# Doctrine2 Datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have the following code, as far as I know, it is OK but it isn't working :S

created_at and updated_at are datetime format...

Any clues?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in D:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\AR\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeT‌​ype.php on line 44

```
public function __construct()
{
    if(!$this->getCreatedAt()){
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
    }

    $this->updated_at = new \DateTime();
}
```

EDIT: I've tried with \DateTime("now"); too but same problem
EDIT2: I've used this, instead of constructor too, but same problem

```
  lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [setCreatedAtValue]
    preUpdate: [setUpdatedAtValue]
```

> 

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setCreatedAtValue()
{
    $this->created_at = new \DateTime('now');
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function setUpdatedAtValue()
{
    $this->updated_at = new \DateTime('now');
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual error message (complete with file and line) as well as a code snippet from that location?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in D:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\AR\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType.php on line 44

Comment: What's the stack trace (please edit your question with this information, don't post it in a comment)?

Comment: I don't know how to get the stack trace... I'm using Symfony2, trhough console, trying to load things with DoctrineFixtures...

Comment: I think I'm just going to change created_at and updated_at to string format, and It will solve the problem..

Comment: You really need to get that stack trace to find the source of the problem. My guess is something is setting one of your `DateTime` fields to a string or other primitive value. Line 44 of *DateTimeType* is only executed on flush

Comment: Are the two properties (`created_at` and `updated_at`) private? Check your code for anything that sets these values.